npm audit fix --force does not work and makes me go back and forth into updates
I'm making this project on react with npm, and while installing dependencies, it keeps telling me
8 vulnerabilities (2 moderate, 6 high) after my npm audit.
When i do npm audit fix --force, it gives me evn more vulnerabilities, and makes me go to a version and another back and forth.
I did try npm audit fix and npm audit to see exactly the issues in order to npm update them all but nothing changes. i also uninstalled everything and reinstalled everything.
When i do npm audit fix --force a second times, it tells me 162 vulnerabilities (1 low, 121 moderate, 37 high, 3 critical)
Here is what it gives me :
# npm audit report

nth-check  <2.0.1
Severity: high
Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in nth-check - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-rp65-9cf3-cjxr
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@3.0.1, which is a breaking change
node_modules/svgo/node_modules/nth-check
  css-select  <=3.1.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of nth-check
  node_modules/svgo/node_modules/css-select
    svgo  1.0.0 - 1.3.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-select
    node_modules/svgo
      @svgr/plugin-svgo  <=5.5.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
      node_modules/@svgr/plugin-svgo
        @svgr/webpack  4.0.0 - 5.5.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/plugin-svgo
        node_modules/@svgr/webpack
          react-scripts  >=2.1.4
          Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
          Depends on vulnerable versions of resolve-url-loader
          node_modules/react-scripts

postcss  <8.4.31
Severity: moderate
PostCSS line return parsing error - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-7fh5-64p2-3v2j
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@3.0.1, which is a breaking change
node_modules/resolve-url-loader/node_modules/postcss
  resolve-url-loader  0.0.1-experiment-postcss || 3.0.0-alpha.1 - 4.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/resolve-url-loader

8 vulnerabilities (2 moderate, 6 high)

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force


i manually updated svgo, nth-check, and react-scripts.
I'm planning to do my back with node,
idk what to do i know i'm missing something that i can't see
Thank you

react-scripts is no longer maintained and deprecated. If you don't want any vulnerabilities, eject CRA and manage its dependencies (and the breaking changes) yourself, or switch to another tool.
